# Ubuntu 14 dual monitor, dual launchers - weird launching behavior

Tags: 14.04, launcher, multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my computer (Pentium G3258 with integrated Intel HD Graphics only) and I have connedted two displays: 22 inches monitor(DVI) plus projector(HDMI) (I run it for movies generally).

I placed launcher on both displays and it works fine but there is one problem. Example scenario:

- on Display1 I have Nautilus opened
- I go to Display2 and from the launcher I want to open another Nautilus - it unfortunately opens on Display1 not 2

Generally most of the time launched apps are placed at Display1.

How to force Ubuntu to launch apps to currently used Display?

Answer (score 0):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

I looked at this issue earlier.

I am pretty sure it's application specific.
The application makes a decision where the window will be placed.

There is a property file where you can specify the position/size and other properties.
But I have not seen display selection properties.

Basically you have to deal with Nautilus.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Nautilus was just an example. I've noticed same behavior with other applications like vlc or chrome.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that every application has it's own positioning properties.